# Local Gitlab server with seflsigned ssl certificat

Tags: ssl, gitlab, ssl-certificate

Hello I configured Gitlab server on a VM OL7. I can easily call the http page. but when I use my self-signed ssl certificate generated using the method offered [here](https://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Setup_HTTPS_for_Gitlab), I can't call my page and I get a timeout as error. My configuration is simple and I have already tried different variants someone could tell me how I can configure this one. note that I don't want to use let's encrypt for this.

this is an example of my `gitlab.rb`

```
external_url 'http://gitlab.icw19.lab'
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.icw19.lab.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.icw19.lab.key"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `external_url` value should include `https://` to indicate that you wish to use SSL on port 443. Then GitLab will listen on 443 and will configure Nginx to use your SSL certificates.

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.icw19.lab'
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.icw19.lab.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.icw19.lab.key"
```